# Decorator or abstract base class? Neither seem right

Tags: c++

I'm writing an interface which basically has two methods `next` which tries to get the next value and `prev` which returns the previous value.

```
struct foo
{
    virtual boost::optional<int> next() = 0;
    virtual int prev() = 0;
};
```

The interface will basically be used by first calling `next`, and if that fails it is possible to get the previous value with `prev`. `prev` is not as trivial as in this example, some other stuff should happen for `prev` values. The `prev` method works pretty much the same for all classes and I would like to provide a default implemention of it.

I have to ways of implementing this, neither of which I like:

First possibility is an abstract base class instead of interface.

```
struct abstract_foo : public foo
{
    int prev_;

    virtual boost::optional<int> next()
    {
        boost::optional<int> val = do_next();
        if(val)
            prev_ = *val;
        return val;        
    }

    int prev()
    {
        return prev_;
    }

    virtual boost::optional<int> do_next() = 0;
};
```

However, it breaks the interface, now one either have to remember to call `abstract_foo::next` or be forced to implement a rather ugly `do_next`.

Another way is using a decorator:

```
struct foo
{
    virtual boost::optional<int> next() = 0;
    virtual int prev()
    {
        throw not_implemented();
    }
};

struct foo_decorator : public foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> foo_;
    int prev_;

    foo_decorator(std::unique_ptr<foo>&& foo)
        : foo_(std::move(foo))
    {
    }

    boost::optional<int> next()
    {
        boost::optional<int> val = foo_->next_value();
        if(val)
            prev_ = *val;
        return val;
    }

    int prev()
    {
        return prev_;
    }
};
```

Here the, `not_implemented` just screams for accidents where users think they can use `prev` directly from the base class.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for good design? Or should I simply have some kind of helper class that help implementing it manually in derived classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option is actually close to the preferred way, which would be as follows:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    boost::optional<int> next()
    {
        boost::optional<int> val = do_next();
        if(val)
            prev_ = val;
        return val;
    }

    int prev()
    {
        return prev_;
    }

  private:
    int prev_;
    virtual boost::optional<int> do_next() = 0;
};
```

Note how `next()` and `prev()` are non-virtual, and `do_next()` is private. [Public non-virtual interface calls private virtual implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

In the second option, why not implement prev already in the base class:

```
struct foo
{
public:
    virtual boost::optional<int> next() = 0;
    int prev()
    {
        return prev_;
    }
protected:
    int prev_;
};

struct foo_decorator : public foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> foo_;

    foo_decorator(std::unique_ptr<foo>&& foo)
        : foo_(std::move(foo))
    {
    }

    boost::optional<int> next()
    {
        boost::optional<int> val = foo_->next_value();
        if(val)
            prev_ = *val;
        return val;
    }
};
```